# Should I assign my various passwords to my keyboard's macro keys?

Tags: passwords, password-management

I had an idea to assign my keyboard's macro keys to various passwords so I can just hit the key and it will paste in (the passwords are long and random so I won't remember them). This is on a home desktop PC. Are there any reasons this is a bad idea security wise?

Comment: Well for starters anyone who gets physical access can just press the macro keys and get your passwords. Also if the macros are programmed/readable from the computer then remote attackers can read them out of it.

Comment: Why use keyboard macros when you can just configure KeePass to basically do the same but securely?

Comment: Not to mention that if your keyboard dies or is stolen, you lose all your passwords. _Availability_ is a component of security.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Keyboard macros are typically implemented in software. I'm not aware of any keyboards which store such macros in _hardware_. That would change things considerably.

Comment: @forest [there are some instances where the macro is recorded and stored on the actual keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/420233/keyboard-with-hardware-macros/845824). Not too common, though but they exist.

Comment: @forest The [Vortex POK3R](http://www.vortexgear.tw/db/upload/webdata4/6vortex_20166523361966663.pdf) is an example of a keyboard which stores macros in its hardware. The instructions are hard to follow but basically you can make a key (or FN + key) type up to 32 keypresses.

Comment: You're probably better off writing your passwords on post-it notes and sticking them to the monitor.

Comment: @Carey Gregory A more secure solution would be to stick the post-it notes to the bottom of they keyboard.  They'll never think to look there.

Comment: @forest I have a keyboard that allows you to make macros in the hardware, and they are all stored in the hardware. No software needed at all. It is some crappy 25€ keyboard.

Comment: This promotes password reusing. If there are 5 macro keys and you have 5 passwords on your keys, I bet you will be reusing these 5 passwords everywhere.

Comment: Now that we've got every single boilerplate security answer in here; I'd say it's a rather good idea. If you have to type your password often, then this will make it faster. If it's your home PC, you lock the house at night, you are not paranoid for constant break-ins and you're careful with what you download, this should be no problem. There's always a risk of someone bricking the window and taking the machine, so you have to decide if you want to accept the associated risks. A breach is a breach.

Comment: @forest I forgot to add this: https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/Accessory/Keyboard_Mouse/E11187_Cerberus_Gaming_Keyboard_Manual.pdf <-- this is the keyboard that I have. And it is actually around 35€, not 25€. Still, cheap enough.

Comment: My office computer on work from home days is a nuisance locking me out every 5 minutes unnecessarily. This is my solution. I'm disappointed I waited this long to discover the OP's solution.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat in such cases I personally prefer to "caffeinate" my computer so that it doesn't go to sleep or locks the screen unless I explicitly do it myself.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

## This is a bad idea.

As [user](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/171722/user) mentioned in a comment, anyone with physical access can just press the assigned macro key and the password will be revealed.

You also have a high chance of accidentally pressing the macro key, thus typing in your password in places where you didn't mean to.

The macro data also needs to be stored somewhere, and is likely stored in plain text. As such, storing your password in a macro is akin to storing it in a plain text file.

Instead, use a password manager. An offline password manager allows you to store your passwords in an encrypted form, protected by a master password. Many offline password managers also include functionality to write your password for you, just like a macro, except that this is much safer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101774/discussion-on-answer-by-mechmk1-keep-password-in-macro).

Comment: While a password manager would be better, I don't see how this is particularly bad.  A remote attacker would need to know that you're storing passwords in your macros and how those macros are stored on your machine in addition to compromising your machine in another way to exploit this.  Or, they'd need physical access (which is game over anyway).  Unless the OP's a specific target, I don't see this raising their risk in any meaningful way.

Comment: @CarlKevinson I'd argue the risk is *losing* the macro. Through whatever means - drive failure, or keyboard breaks (assuming it's stored on the keyboard itself), or maybe just somebody mindlessly deleting the file. Now you're locked out of your account(s) which is an inconvenience. So, it's *similar* to using a password manager (let's disregard the security of storage as a factor) but worse, since the *availability* goes down.

Comment: @CarlKevinson "An attacker would have to know" is not in accordance with [Kerkhoff's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle). A system must be secure even under the assumption that the attacker knows everything about it.

Comment: The chance of "_accidentally pressing the macro key_" has happened to me once or twice when focus is on a Skype window instead of my ssh session!

Comment: @MechMK1 Kerkhoff's Principle does not apply - we're not designing a crypto system.

Comment: @MooseBoys It does very much apply here, as security by design is *always* preferable to security by obscurity. But feel free to design your systems based on obscurity.

Comment: @MechMK1 prior to using a password manager, I personally used a password scheme of the form `password = f(weak password, service name)`. Knowing the implementation of `f` would significantly decrease the serucity of my scheme. However, it met the needs of my threat model which was to avoid automated compromise based on leaks of unsalted password databases. When it comes to password management, "Usability is Security" is the golden rule.

Comment: `You also have a high chance of accidentally pressing the macro key, thus typing in your password in places where you didn't mean to.` - This is only really an issue if whomever knows what the password is for, otherwise it's little mrore than just a string of characters without meaning.... unless your're dumb enough to use the same password for everything

Comment: @ggdx You can give that point more weight by posting the password of a random service that you use.

Comment: @MechMK1 I think the real thing is can you quickly change the password - `2*R_dc13` is a password that I stored in my password manager at some time in the recent past.  It may or may not be a password to some service.  I may or may not change it in the near future.

Comment: @emory The real tragedy is that you are using an [8 character password](https://twitter.com/tinkersec/status/1096046635593928704).

Comment: @MechMK1 I agree.  I might have changed it.

Comment: @MechMK1 - Sure - `MrBurns987!`

Comment: @MechMK1 This is not security by obscurity though, this is exchanging something you know for something you have. Also, Kerkhoff's principle doesn't apply to personal systems because the system itself is the key.

Comment: @Fax As you said, the system itself is the key. `f(weak password, service name)` is such a commonly employed system that any even remotely sophisticated attacker will try that when cracking a hash. It's a shit system, and people who use it are trying to justify it to themselves. If I had the choice between using `hunter2@StackExchange` or `;kKvuhh_hzTJ7SCK_*<cr`, I know which one I would pick.

Comment: @MechMK1 You're making an analogy which simply does not work. Something you have is not equivalent to a weak password. If that were the case, two-factor authentication would be no more secure than one-factor.

Comment: @Fax What on earth made you think any of this is related to 2FA?

Comment: @MechMK1 I assumed your second sentence about weak passwords was related to the first about the system being the key, but in hindsight that seems to not be the case. I only intended to challenge your answer and your first comment, not that weak passwords are bad.

Comment: I had this for a while. I _often_ ended up accidentally typing it in terminals. Like, `sudo ...` where `sudo`, or whatever the command was was mistyped, I hit enter, then <password key> then <enter>. Boom. Password in plaintext in bash history. Or when someone was sitting beside me, and I accidentally hit it and my whole password showed up in plain text.

Comment: I have accidentally released a FIDO v1 PW in a chat program.  Good news: Immediately using it in the correct place invalidated the one I'd released into the wild.  Macro'd PWs will not have this advantage.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a good idea. As far as the fact that “anyone could have access” to your macro keys, and besides the fact that they would  you have to know where and how to use the passwords and that they’re even programmed TO the keys, your threat here is largely the same threat any homeowner faces against potential intruders.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I don't want to sound rude or mean, but your answer does not add anything valuable to the answers. The danger of misclicking and hence revealing the password (even if you don't know where is belongs to) is a threat. Also there are web apps, which usually (without hacks) need permission to read your QMK or VIA programming which is usually the case so theoretically it can be read out remotely...

Comment: @SirMuffington - I disagree. A lot of these risks are not applicable to everyone's setup. "Good security" means overdoing what is necessary, and things like this give the user back the authority to decide what consequences they are ok with.

Comment: While there are a lot of risks associated with the proposed idea, ultimately the answer depends on such thing as a threat model. If the risks have low probability and the benefits outweigh the risks, in a particular use case, then why not?

Answer (score 0):

@MechMK1's answer needs at least some additions:

> anyone with physical access can just press the assigned macro key and the password will be revealed

In lots of cases, this is pure advantage. And even if the environment is dangerous, there is an option to store passwords not in keyboard, but in separate additional mouse which is only plugged/used for storing passwords. This way it gets closer to classic pen and paper storage.
You will get separate additional mouse as soon as you brake wheel on the previous one.

And even better - you can take this mouse while moving somewhere and always have up-to-date passwords with very fast access without cloud storage / master password leak risk.

> You also have a high chance of accidentally pressing the macro key, thus typing in your password in places where you didn't mean to.

Lots of mice have DPI switch mode, which also switches macros on each button. Put passwords on specifically low DPI mode and problem solved.

> The macro data also needs to be stored somewhere, and is likely stored in plain text. As such, storing your password in a macro is akin to storing it in a plain text file.

This is exactly main question, but some mouses support IO only under USB 3.0. So you can plug in 3.0, write passwords, then always use USB 2.0 which guarantees no way to download them from your keyboard\mouse.

So final answer is probably that it

- was great storage until not widely used/ widely known,
- nowadays it's a bit unsafe option,
- when mouse developers realize this is perfect hardware storage and will add special switch to block IO, this again will be safe and promising